# TFS Build - Publish specific build from drop folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

We currently use TFS to deploy builds to our servers in different environments such as QA, PreProd and Prod.  In the current method, the build agent gets all latest from TFS, builds and publishes to whichever environment specified.

I know that you can actually just publish just to a drop folder where it creates PublishedWebsites folder, but how can you publish to servers from drop folder mentioning specific build?  For example, there may be build #7, which our QA team has certified.  We want to make sure that that is the build that is going to production and not latest content which might have some check ins from other team members.

Any help would be appreciated.  I referred this link, but it is mentioning about overriding OutputRoot directory in publish.proj file, which is not created in the solution that we created using Visual Studio 2012.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/deploying-a-specific-build

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple way of solving the needs.

The best option is to use LabManagement; it will take care of computing the correct Drop folder. See [Using a Lab Environment for Your Application Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997438.aspx) for details. The idea is to use the [build-deploy-test workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495.aspx) to deploy and run tests on a group of machines running Test Agent.

You can setup a more sophisticated process using Release Management, a new feature of TFS 2013 that you can add to 2012 as well. It offers to design your promotion process and control who authorizes deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You should neither use Build or Lab Management to do deployments. Both are poor solutions for this as this is not what they were designed for. 
Microsoft added a dedicated release management tool with visual studio 2013. I have configured and used it with both 2012 & 2013.

http://nakedalm.com/building-release-pipeline-release-management-visual-studio-2013/

This will be much easier than either of the other tools.

Comment: Thank you, we are using visual studio online for TFS and all I have is a build server that is configured for our use.  Installing release management server will involve installing SQL Server, which we do not want to do at this moment.  I was thinking that there is an easier way of picking the build output from the Drop folder and publishing it to different environments

Comment: I just setup this for a customer on Azure so you don't need to install anything locally. You can also use SQL Server express, which is free, to host the DB.